# Flask - temp CSV to be read by D3 empty

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, flask, python-3.7

I currently have the problem when creating a temporary CSV file which should be read by D3.js. For some reason, it is always seen as empty.

If I copy and paste the contents of dataframe `df` into e.g. `test.csv` and use `d3.csv("test.csv", ...` then it runs without any problems and the `console.log(data)` returns an array of size 31. However, using the Flask URL, I get an empty array `[]` as the output for `console.log(data)`.

Weirdly enough both the `print("starting", file=sys.stderr)` and `print(buffer, file=sys.stderr)` never executes (at least it is not shown on the console) which leads me to believe that the entire `get_d3_data(doc_id)` function is never run even though the Flask URL `/query/csv/<doc_id>` is called.

In the Flask debug log traceback, `GET /query/8 HTTP/1.1" 200 -` which is the URL containing the D3.js code is the last to be called and `GET /query/csv/8` is never called.

**EDIT:** I just discovered in the browser network tab that `/query/csv/{{doc_id}}` is being called but does not appear in my Flask debug log for some reason. Also, as mentioned before, the `prints` I put within the function seems to never execute which leads me to believe that the D3.js code calls the correct Flask URL, but the function never executes.

Furthermore, `console.log(d3.csv('/query/csv/{{doc_id}}'));` returns `{header: ƒ, mimeType: ƒ, responseType: ƒ, response: ƒ, get: ƒ, …}` where most variables such as `header arguments` and `row arguments` are `null`.

**FLASK CODE**

```
from flask import Flask, json, render_template, send_file
import gensim
import gensim.models as g
import smart_open
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
...
@app.route('/query/csv/<doc_id>')
def get_d3_data(doc_id):
    print("starting", file=sys.stderr)
    ...    
    #code to make dataframe df
    ...
    buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(buffer, encoding='utf-8')
    buffer.seek(0)
    print(buffer, file=sys.stderr)
    return send_file(buffer, mimetype='text/csv')
```

**HTML CODE**

```
...
   d3.csv("/query/csv/{{doc_id}}", function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        console.log(data);
...
```

**Browser network tab**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify `as_attachment=true` in `send_file`:

```
return send_file(buffer, mimetype='text/csv', as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding `as_attachment` gives me `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/query/csv/8 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)` and `Uncaught XMLHttpRequest` which is caught by `if (error) throw error;`

Comment: Oops I forgot to add the Python side of the error which is `TypeError: filename unavailable, required for sending as attachment`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Content-Disposition` to tell the browser to download the file.

```
resp = flask.make_response(df.to_csv())
resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
return resp
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the same problem. It seems like `d3.csv("/query/csv/{{doc_id}}..."` never activates the Flask function and it doesn't seem to be the problem of the Flask function itself.

Comment: Scratch that. From the browser network tab, it turns out that `/query/csv/{{doc_id}}` is being called but the function does not seem to execute (or the called Flask URL is not recognized by Flask).

Comment: Just want to update. I forced the execution of the code but got `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/query/csv/8 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)` and `XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}` both of which were caught by `if (error) throw error;`. Furthermore, with `console.log(d3.csv('/query/csv/{{doc_id}}'));` I get the same empty output as when using the buffer code (I have edited my original post with additional information) but with the aforementioned errors.